# Can't remove duplicates from MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm having hard time removing duplicates from database. It's MariaDB (protocol version: 10, 10.3.34-MariaDB Server). I need to remove rows where three columns are equal. I was trying to use WITH clause but database throws error that it can't recognize 'WITH', so I focused on traditional way.

I need to remove rows where `foreignId`, `column1` and `column2` are equal.

I'm checking if there are duplicates like

```
SELECT foreignId, column1, column2, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY foreignId, column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Trying to remove duplicates...

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    p.id,
    p.foreignId,
    p.column1,
    p.column2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY 
        p.column1, 
        p.column2, 
        p.foreignId
      ORDER BY
        p.foreignId,
        p.column2,
        p.column1
    ) AS row_number
  FROM table1 p
  GROUP BY p.foreignId, p.column1, p.column2
) dup
ON table1.column1 = dup.column1
WHERE dup.row_number > 1;
```

I was modifying this code alot but still can't make it work as intended... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When there are duplicates, what defines the row to be kept?

Comment: Well it doesn't really matter, but would be better to keep newer ones. id is uuid but there is a timestamp column. So greater timestamp is to keep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique column like id, you can do following:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID NOT IN 
(SELECT x.id FROM
(SELECT MAX(id) id, MAX(foreignId) foreignId, 
MAX(column1) column1, MAX(column2) column2
FROM table1 
WHERE ttimestamp IN (SELECT MAX(ttimestamp) FROM table1 
GROUP BY foreignID, column1, column2)
GROUP BY foreignId, column1, column2)x);
```

Please see the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6ff4cd091989929ba994e68a259dba67)

Comment: This query doesn't necessarily work as it is dependent on `timestamp` being ordered the same way as `id`. See for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=80586d88ac72f8288bda4aa8cbdbb679

Comment: It also violates the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql mode which may be enabled, dependent on OPs environment

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I think it's very unlikely that it will really fail in the author's situation, but of course, he can prefer your propose if this works better for him :) I have to work now, but maybe I will correct it later. Or you do if you want.

Comment: I have math concern on both this methods. They both now affecting 218 rows. But running this checking code gives me 167 rows (each got at least count 2, 21 rows got count 3, 4 rows got count 4, 4 rows got count 5, one row got count 6 and one row count 8. So things to delete would be (7 + 5 + 4x4 + 4x3 + 21x2 + 136) = 239.  Why it is affecting 218 then?

Comment: 7+5+4*4+4*3+21*2+136 = 218 on my calculator...

Comment: Whoops I went 21* 3 instead of 2 xD Sorry, it's getting late haha. So it's all good! Thanks for help both of you :)

Comment: What's OP? I'm not sure if I follow? To get them in order by when added, we need to sort by timestamp.

Comment: In my opinion, the risk of my propose failing is very low in common environments since in ususal cases, the id corresponds to the timestamp, meaning rows having the highest id also have the newest timestamp. But of course, if this is not the case, my query could fail (thanks to Nick who shows this situation in his example). Since, as I said, I have to work now and I don't want to create a solution within two seconds, I will have a look later or maybe someone else can fix it.

Comment: @Smokovsky OP = original poster (i.e. you :)

Comment: I found some time to review and change my query, so it will work better now. Anyway, I think the OP's question is answered in a sufficiant way now and he can solve his further issues on his own. Thank you all for the interesting topic and thanks to Nick for pointing out possible risks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues with your query:

1. You need to remove the `GROUP BY` in the subquery
2. You should change the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause to `ORDER BY p.ts DESC` (where `ts` is the name of your timestamp column)
3. You need to `JOIN` on the unique `id` column; otherwise you will delete any row which has values which have duplicates anywhere i.e. `ON table.id = dup.id`

That will give you:

```sql
DELETE table1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    p.id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY 
        p.column1, 
        p.column2, 
        p.foreignId
      ORDER BY
        p.ttimestamp DESC
    ) AS rn
  FROM table1 p
) dup
ON table1.id = dup.id
WHERE dup.rn > 1
```

Note I would not use `row_number` as a column alias as it is a reserved word, so I've changed it to `rn` above.

Demo (thanks to @JonasMetzler) on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=30b40a5183d4ad15896804ecbabf8022)

Note that if it's possible for duplicate rows to also have the same timestamp value, this query will delete a random selection of those rows. If you want a deterministic result, change the `ORDER BY` clause to

```
      ORDER BY
        p.ttimestamp DESC,
        p.id DESC
```

which will keep the row with the highest (or lowest if you remove the `DESC` after `p.id`) `id` value.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a88f8bbed9a929b05b6d7410712bb7b9)

Comment: This does not work correctly and removes too many rows, see example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=ec1e5fd07e091f6703700ea487491fe1

Comment: @JonasMetzler thanks again, I've corrected the query and borrowed your fiddle for a demo

Comment: You're welcome, thank you ;)

Comment: @Smokovsky apologies for the mis-step, I've corrected the query.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for your help! It works fine now

Comment: As so often, there are many ways. I think this one is also good, so I upvote it.

Comment: @JonasMetzler thanks - will happily do the same if you can resolve the issues with yours

Comment: @JonasMetzler OP says "greater timestamp is to keep" in the comments to the question. Since both those entries have the same timestamp, there isn't really any way to decide which to keep. If this was an issue, one could simply change the `ORDER BY` clause to `ORDER BY p.ttimestamp DESC, p.id DESC` which resolves that issue. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a88f8bbed9a929b05b6d7410712bb7b9